# how to apply multiple count in hive query

Tags: hive, pyspark, hiveql

i have table of 2 columns act,dst in hive:

```
  act      dst  
  success  Info
  success  High
  failure  medium
  Blank    low
  failure  Info
```

I want to count of every field of act columns like

```
    act     count  
    success  2     
    failue   2     
    Blank    1
```

Also if it is possible to find for both columns its good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`group by`** and aggregation as **`count(*)`** in your select query

**Try with this query:**

```
select act,count(*) from <table_name> group by act;
```